# Why i cant use the following string build?

Tags: java, android

I got a `String myString ="\/Date(1432647212000+0200)\/";`

It gives me the error Illegal escape character in string literal
Ive searched and people recommend to use this format

```
String myString ="\\/Date(1432647212000+0200)\\/";
```

But my problem is when i use this string it gives me 
`"\\/Date(1432647212000+0200)\\/"`, but i need `"\/Date(1432647212000+0200)\/"`

Comment: what if you just use "/Date(1432647212000+0200)/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s ="\\/Date(1432647212000+0200)\\/";
System.out.println(s);
```

will print

`\/Date(1432647212000+0200)\/`

But it depends on what do you mean by "I need it to be...", because in this case the string you declare is different from the one you need, but gets printed out as the right one

Comment: i use the following string in json builder and prints the other option

Comment: if you declare `String s ="\/Date(1432647212000+0200)\/";` you can be sure that your String contains that exact sequence of characters. If you try to print it, anyway, the result will be different.

Comment: the idea is that i need "\/Date(1432647212000+0200)\/" , but this doesnt allow me to use it

I print 1 string , but when i use that string in json builder it uses the string indicated